# Use 'def' define a function in clojure

Tags: clojure

Here is two functions which request the same arguments and return the same boolean type value.
Such as:

```
 (defn Foo1 [x] (< x 3))
 (defn Foo2 [x] (> x -10))
```

But I am confused when I define the function below:

```
 (def Foo3 (or Foo1 Foo2))
```

Can you guys tell me how it works. Thank you very much!

Comment: `(def Foo3 (some-fn Foo1 Foo2))` will also give you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(defn f [a] a)` is just shortcut for `(def f (fn [a] a))`

If your second argument to the `def` binding is a function, then first argument is function also.

Comment: In my example.When I call Foo3 with an agrument which I want to get two return from Foo1 and Foo2 respectively.But in fact,Foo3 just skip Foo2 and return the value which is from Foo1

Comment: Just because `or` evaluates first paremeter to true, and then not needed to calculate next one, because whole result is true.

Comment: It seems not that case. I have try even Foo1 return false, the second function Foo2 is not called.And Foo3 will return whatever Foo1 has returned.

Comment: I see, you missed parameters to your helper functions. The problem that `(or Foo1 Foo2)` do not call functions at all. Function itself evaluates to true so your result is always true. Working example: `(def Foo3 #(or (Foo1 %) (Foo2 %)))`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to combine the conditions, you probably want:

```
(defn foo3 [x] (or (foo1 x) (foo2 x)))
```

That is, you are defining a new function `foo3` whose result is the result of or-ing the results of calling `foo1` and `foo2` with the same parameter `x`.

**P.S.** It's conventional to name functions in lowercase in Clojure.

Comment: Thank you.That is what I want, but I want to know how my problem comes from.